# Add Controllers from Class Library with unique routing rule for entire class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

.NET Core 2.0 appears to have made things much easier to split mvc into module libraries by simply adding a controller inherited class in a class library and then calling:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName)))
        .AddControllersAsServices();
```

But I imagine this just adds the controllers to the default routing rule, unless I add a specific Route attribute above the controller method.

If I have separated entire module logic into a single class library, I want this entire library to have a routing rule of http://{root}/ModuleName instead of having to add a route rule to every controller method as an attribute. Essentially the default routing rule would not be used in my application. The application would be made of modules that are all isolated libaries and each module name is appended to the root URL.

I imagine I can hack this up manually, by manually adding routing rules referencing the namespace of the controllers like .NET 4.5, but is there an easier way?

It appears .NET Core is trying to enable what I want, but not my use case, unless I am missing something?

If I add an area routing rule e.g

```
routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I can then use area's for this functionality to occur on a controller level e.g

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

Could I automate the area routing rule by creating a inheritable class that inherits from the base controller class that handles the routing?